# Tilde slash Account Login not working in MVC4 after conversion to SimpleMembership

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

In my web.config I have:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

as well as:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Any redirects caused by [Authorize] controller or action filter fails to work in my production environment. I get a 302 to a URL with the ~ in it i.e.:

```
<a href="/~/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FTransactions">
```

However it works locally - I get the correct 302 to:

```
<a href="/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FTransactions">
```

I have a workaround - which involves dropping the ~ from the loginUrl. But why doesn't it work with the ~ in production?

Some additional info:
Local server (IIS Express w VS 2012):

```
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 4.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

Production server:

```
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 4.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```